# Sphinx обработка "с" и "без"

Tags: sphinx, sphinxapi

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, кто-нибудь решал проблему связанную с попаданием в поисковую выдачу товаров, а названии которых фигурирует часть запроса, но с частицей "без".

Пример *"душевая кабина без бани"*,

ответ содержит

```
Душевая кабина Appollo с баней
Душевая кабина Eago
Душевой бокс Niagara без бани
```

та же история с поиском "душевая кабина с баней".

В остальном результаты поиска валидны и полностью устраивают! Поэтому менять алгоритмы не хочется, интересует чужой опыт

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил данную проблему установкой веса. То есть если в поступившем запросе есть такие слова как "с", "без" то давать им максимальный вес.

```
// after sphinx initialize
$searchTerms = (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']))? $_GET['search'] : null;
$words = explode(' ', $searchTerms);
foreach($words => $word) {
if (in_array($word, $strongWords) {
     $weights['name'] = 9999;
     sphinx->setFieldWeights($weights);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть "без" попала в стоп слова? и сфинкс не учитывает её при индексации, то есть для него фразы "Душевой бокс Niagara без бани" и "Душевой бокс Niagara бани" одинаковы